# Django OperationalError at new model object

Tags: python, django

I created a system with Django. My model was working until I added a new field but when I add new field it gives an error. My new field is `owner_id`

> OperationalError at /pdfs/ no such column:
> financial_analysis_pdf.owner_id_id

How Can I fix it?

**models.py**

```
class Pdf(models.Model):
    CHOICES = [
        ..
    ]

    STAT = [
        ...

    ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select', choices=CHOICES)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**pdfs.html**

```
    <tbody id="myTable">
                
                    {% for pdf in pdfs %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="/ocr" >{{ pdf.title }} </a></td>
                            <td>{{ pdf.year }}</td>
                            <td>{{ pdf.type }}</td>
                            <td> <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color: #71ca51"></i></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ pdf.pdf.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  target="_blank">Download</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post" action="{% url 'pdf_delete' pdf.pk %}">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
    
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this analyse?');"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
    
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

**views.py**

```
    def pdf_list(request):
        pdfs = Pdf.objects.all().order_by('-year')
        return render(request, 'pdf_list.html', {'pdfs': pdfs})
```

**customer/model.py**

```
Class Customer(models.Model):

    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

**traceback**

```
    Environment:
    
    
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pdfs/
    
    Django Version: 3.1.4
    Python Version: 3.8.7
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'register',
     'customer',
     'financial_analysis',
     'ocr',
     'crispy_forms',
     'ckeditor']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
    
    
    Template error:
    In template C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\templates\base.html, error at line 0
       no such column: financial_analysis_pdf.owner_id_id
       1 : <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
       2 : <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       3 : <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       4 : <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
       5 : 
       6 : <!DOCTYPE html>
       7 : <html lang="en">
       8 : 
       9 : <head>
       10 :     {% load static %}
    
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    
    The above exception (no such column: financial_analysis_pdf.owner_id_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\financial_analysis\views.py", line 8, in pdf_list
        return render(request, 'pdf_list.html', {'pdfs': pdfs})
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
        return template.render(context, request)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
        len_values = len(values)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 269, in __len__
        self._fetch_all()
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
        self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    
    Exception Type: OperationalError at /pdfs/
    Exception Value: no such column: financial_analysis_pdf.owner_id_id
```

**base.html**

```
<li class="sidebar-dropdown">
          {% load customer_list %}

            {% get_customers request.user as customers %}

            {% for customer in customers %}

            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
              <span>{{customer.customer_name}}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/customers/{{ customer.id }}/profile">View</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/customers/{{ customer.id }}/update"> Update</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/pdfs">Analyses</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
              {% endfor %}
          </li>
```

Comment: did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands?

Comment: What's your base.html like?

Comment: Are you supposed to refer to ```financial_analysis_pdf.owner_id.id```?  Note the ```.``` and not ```_```

Comment: @ewong I added base.html file. There is only sidebar with customer list and owner_id refers to my customer's id

Comment: What's your ```Customer``` model like?

Comment: @ewong I added customer/model.py

Comment: Please include the ```pdf_list.html```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we update our models in django we have to give a default value for already existing objects. so you can follow the below step.

1. Update models with a default value like below -

owner_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")

2. Now you after saving this you can run command (if you're using VS Code)- python manage.py makemigrations
3. The last step to run the command - python manage.py migrate.

After following these step you should not get the error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're supposed to refer to `financial_analysis.owner_id.id`. Note the full-stop as opposed to the underscore.